# Cramér–Rao Lower Bound and UMVUE for $\frac1{\theta}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, inference, estimators, fisher-information

**Problem:** Find the UMVUE of $\frac1\theta$ for a random sample from the population distribution with density $$f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$$ and show that its variance reaches the Cramér–Rao lower bound.

**Progress:** Knowing that the Cramér–Rao Lower Bound is $\frac{\gamma(\theta)^2}{nI(\theta)}$, where $\gamma(\theta)^2=\left(-\frac1{\theta^2}\right)^2=\frac1{\theta^4}$, I then compute the Fisher Information $I(\theta)$. This is where I get lost and become unsure about my work, mostly due to computation.

$$
\begin{align}
I(\theta)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\partial\log{f(x;\theta)}}{\partial\theta}\right)^2\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\frac{\partial f(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta}}{f(x;\theta)}\right)^2f(x;\theta)\partial x \\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\left(\frac{\partial f(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2}{f(x;\theta)}\partial x \\
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\theta}+\log{x})(x^{\theta-1}+(\theta^2-\theta)x^{\theta-2}\right)\partial x \\
&=\left[\log{x}\frac{x^\theta}{\theta}-\frac{x^{\theta-1}}{\theta-1}+\theta(\log{x})x^{\theta-1}\right]\biggr\rvert_0^1\\
&=\frac{-1}{\theta-1}
\end{align}
$$

**I computed this and consistently got a negative answer, which doesn't make sense as plugging that into the CRLB formula yields a negative variance.** I'd really appreciate if someone could quickly help me out on this!

Edit: I found out my mistake! It's a rather stupid one at the fourth equal sign: $$=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\partial\log{f(x;\theta)}}{\partial\theta}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f(x;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right)$$ where I partially integrate the second term with respect to $x$ rather to to $\theta$.

Comment: You don't need to find the Cramér-Rao bound because the score function is of the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f(x;\theta)=k(\theta)\left(T(x)-\frac1{\theta}\right)$. This is the equality condition of Cramér-Rao equality. If $T$ is unbiased for $1/\theta$ then it must be UMVUE with its variance attaining the C-R bound.

Comment: Hi @StubbornAtom, that's an interesting concept I think I either haven't learned or fully internalized yet. Are there any lecture notes or sources you can direct me to on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't follow your working after $\int_0^1\frac{\left(\frac{\partial f(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2}{f(x;\theta)}d x$, note that this expression is nonnegative as the function being integrated is nonnegative.

Let $u = 1 + \theta \log x, \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\theta}x$,

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\left(\frac{\partial f(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2}{f(x;\theta)}d x \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\left( x^{\theta-1}+\theta x^{\theta -1} \log x\right)^2}{\theta x^{\theta -1}}\, dx \\
&=\frac1{\theta}\int_0^1 x^{\theta-1}(1+\theta \log x)^2 \, dx \\
&= \frac1{\theta} \int_{-\infty}^1 x^{\theta-1}u^2 \frac{x}{\theta}\, du \\
&= \frac1{\theta^2} \int_{-\infty}^1 x^\theta u^2 \, du\\
&= \frac1{\theta^2} \int_{-\infty}^1 e^{u-1}u^2 \, du\\
&= \frac1{\theta^2} \left[ e^{u-1}u^2|_{-\infty}^1 - 2\int_{-\infty}^1 ue^{u-1}\, du \right]\\
&=\frac1{\theta^2} \left[ 1-2\left[ e^{u-1}u|_{-\infty}^1-\int_{-\infty}^1 e^{u-1}\, du\right]\right]\\
&= \frac1{\theta^2} \ge 0
\end{align}